# Can't check if data exists in firebase due to unique id container

Tags: javascript, json, database, firebase

I am using [`.push()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push) to store data in firebase. Due to this it is contained inside a unique id, so for example:

```
ref.push({
   myObject: {
      title: "Some Title"
   }
});
```

This is how it appears inside a database:

[image]

I need to check if data that I am pushing to the firebase does not already exist in there, so compare `myObject` that is being pushed to all `myObject` instances stored in the database. I can't figure how to do this as there are these unique id's that nest `myObject` instances inside them.

Note: this is just an example in reality `myObject` contains way more children than title, therefore each of these children need to be compared, hence whole `myObject`.

Reference to firebase: `var ref = new Firebase('https://myurl.firebaseio.com/Objects');`

I tried figuring this out with security checks, in app code, but this unique id really confuses me in how it nests myObject.

Related resource: http://firebase.com

Comment: The unique ID would be covered by a so-called $ variable in Firebase's security rules: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-dollar-variables. But there's no way to test in the Firebase security language whether a double-nested child exists somewhere else in Firebase already. Nor is there a way to query all `Objects` on `title` in the data structure you've chosen. It sounds like you might need a different data structure.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm open to suggestions, if you could provide alternative data structure and way to compare it, that would be awesome.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen My only requirement at the moment is to be able to compare information stored inside unique id instances to one being pushed to the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227966/check-firebase-for-an-existing-object-based-on-attributes-prevent-duplicates

Comment: @mccannf I feel like there should be a more straight forward solution? All that hashing seems like such a complex way to achieve this.

Comment: @mccannf posted link is correct.  follow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to compare complete objects (all properties),  the correct solution is to generate a hash string on save.   This hash would practically be you "unique id / primary key",   so you'll easily know if exists and optionally overwrite/merge/etc...

in firebase, don't use push (*as you don't want the priority*), but keep set your structure to:  `/myObjects/<hashkey> = {...}`  or with another supporting index list,  as suggested by @mccannf link here:  [Check firebase for an existing object based on attributes, prevent duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227966/check-firebase-for-an-existing-object-based-on-attributes-prevent-duplicates)